# Enable Picamera with QT application operating on a custom Yocto image

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto, picamera

If I want to enable CSI pi camera with QT application operating on a custom Yocto image, from where shall I know the packages and configurations needed to be added in my recipe, image recipe and configuration files.

I already have my custom layer with my recipe in it, but I don't know the needed packages and configurations needed to be added.